# Prevent jQuery UI tabs from automatically loading content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Consider a page like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="first">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="second">Second</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabContent" class="ui-tabs-panel">
    This is the content of the “First” tab!
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$("#tabs").tabs({
  select: function() { return false; },
  selected: 0
});
</script>
```

Despite the fact that `select` returns `false`, when the content of `first` will be loaded when the `selected` is set.

Is it possible to prevent jQuery UI's tabs from automatically loading this?

Comment: Ricardo, it could be that something was wrong with your jquery code? Do you mind sharing your code so that we could possibly find the issue?

Comment: Sure, just to give some background,what is happening is that the tab widget always loads the url in the tab link in the body of the tab, so if the url is a full page it will be loaded inside the body of the tab. Here's the code im using :

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){    
// Tabs   
$('#tabs').tabs({ selected: 1 }); //this is to select the rite tab on load 
$('#tabs').tabs({
select: function(event, ui) {
var url = $.data(ui.tab, 'load.tabs');
if( url ) {
  location.href = url;
  return false;
}
return true;
}
});               
});
</script>

Comment: Could be related to base tag/tabs issues : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025765/jquery-ui-tabs-with-base-href-and-query-string-doesnt-work