# jQuery ui tabs with base href and query string doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

The jQuery ui tabs is working for me but when I place a query string behind it, it will load in the base href content.

Maybe i'm not understanding the correct behaviour of base href/relative links. But here is my set up:
Base href: http://example.com/ . 
Relative link: random/link/example.do.
 Hastag like so: #fragment-1 .
Full link: http://example.com/random/link/example#fragment-1

That's how my link looks like. When i put a query string behind it, it will not work. Like so:
http://example.com/random/link/example?refresh=2

I found some fixes that adjust the source code. ([link](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8851)). But is there a way to fix this without adjusting the source code?

Thanks

Comment: I've encountered this bug before. I'll suggest you use an older/earlier version of JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey it's horrible but you can try this

```
$(function () {
    var rquery = /\?[^#]*/;
    $("#tabs").find("a").each(function() {
        this.setAttribute("data-orig-href", this.href);
        this.href = this.href.replace( rquery, "" );
    });

    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mYZF7/4/) to show it working.